# Algorithm used in the game Ruzzle

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have been thinking about the algorithm used in the game [Ruzzle](http://www.ruzzle-game.com) for a while. The aim in the game is to find the presence of any word in a given grid, word can be matched in any direction up-down, down-up, left-right, right-left, both diagonals up and down etc.

Let's make it simple. Find a given word in a 2-D grid with the same matching constraints (directions). What is the algorithm with the best time-complexity possible ?

For example, FOREVER can be found in this grid.

H **O F** E R

L **R E** T O

S N **V** O **R**

P Q T **E** N

Comment: I'd say: Pick a starting cell, do DFS or BFS, without visiting cells twice, as long as the so-far path is a prefix in a list of known words. Remember all the complete words you find, and repeat for each possible starting point. Edit: Oh, a _given_ word... forget it, this was for finding all the words.

Comment: @Geobits I thought of this solution. Isn't there anything better than this algorithm ?

Comment: You should [include your research/ideas/attempts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the question to save time. We can't know what you've thought of unless you tell us.

Comment: Are you interested in finding all words in a given dictionary in a given puzzle instance?  For an n-word dictionary this can be done in only O(nlog n) extra one-off preprocessing time, and O(log n) time per lookup, beyond tobias_k's approach.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Can you please elaborate on finding a given word first and then move on to explaining how can we search for words in a given dictionary of words ?

Comment: tobias_k's way is just a slightly more formal statement of Geobits's, except he doesn't make the mistake of claiming a too-low time complexity (there will be a lot more than O(s*n*k) paths).  To look for all words in a dictionary, first sort the dictionary lexicographically.  Now perform the same search as before, but maintain a *valid range* in this sorted array -- i.e. the range containing all dictionary words having prefix equal to the current path.  This range progressively narrows as the path gets longer, and widens again when you backtrack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further optimise it by using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. Once you fill-in the structure with all the English words (or a different language), than you can check in O(1) if a particular neighbour character needs to be explored or not.

Please, notice that at this point you are *trading storage for time*: you presumably will need more RAM to store the entire Trie but you will query it faster than checking in the ordered list of words.

In terms of architecture behind the game, I think they use a dedicated server, which works full time to store in a DB new games (matrixes) and their list of admissible words. During the game, your device receives an ID, it downloads the matrix and the list of admissible words and this is enough to allow you to play. At the end of each game everything is deleted and the final score (just an integer) is submitted to the server, which will update your profile. In the actual game there's something more because they also have badges and statistics (but that's trivial stuff to collect). Bear in mind that this is just the way I would design and develop it.

What do you think? Can we do even better?

Answer (score -2):

I have created a course about making ruzzle game mechanics in Unity. Please check it out and you will find exact answers:

https://www.udemy.com/word-game-unity/?couponCode=wordgamecourse

Comment: This answer is close to being spam (you do disclose your affiliation), but  read [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) as advice on improving your post.